# TouchUpInside on UIView with children

Tags: iphone, uiview-hierarchy, touch-up-inside

I may be missing something here, but...

I have a `UIView` with a few children (a couple of `UILabel`'s and `UIImageView`).  I need to catch an event when the user clicks (taps) anywhere within the parent `UIView` - visible part of the `UIView` or any of its children).

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can change the UIView's class in the Identity Inspector ... make it `UIControl` and then you can add an event for `UITouchUpInside` for your view - to catch the taps on it.

Good luck!

EDIT: here's a step-by-step with screenshots:

The view...
[image: Original view - of type UIView]

... of course, no events.
[image: UIView has no events you can use]

Go back and change UIView with UIControl and...
[image: Change UIView to UIControl]

Ta-daa! Events!
[image: UIControl allows you to use events]

Hook a method to the UITouchUpInside event
[image: Add event for UITouchUpInside]

This is how it should look like in the interface file
[image: The interface of the method]

This is how it should look like in the implementation file (you can, of course, replace the logging with anything you want)
[image: The implementation of the method]

Comment: @WebOrCode: I've edited my answer and added screenshots, hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

You can feign this behaviour by having a gesture recogniser for your parent view and ensuring that your children do not have their own gesture recognisers. To do this add a gesture recogniser to your parent `UIView` that listens for taps. Where `parentView` is the containing view for your child views (`UILabels`/`UIImageView`) and `handleTap` is a method implemented by `parentView`, do something like:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *tapParent = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:parentView action:@selector(handleTap)];
[parentView addGestureRecognizer:tapParent];
[tapParent release];
```

As your child views do not have their own gesture recognisers they will not 'eat' the gesture and so the parent view will respond so long as you tap within its bounds.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

**Swift 3**

```
 let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selector(self.customViewClick))
withSender: self)
 customView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)


 func customViewClick()  {
     print("custom view clicked!")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to give a bit more details because there are multiple options.

If you want the normal tap you can catch one of the standard touch events and see what subview got the event. Something like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(touch.view != self.mySubViewOfInterest)
    {
        // perform my actions
    }
}
```

If you need complex gesture recognition then you can use one of the UIGestureRecognizer and assign it to the subviews or main view.

Anyway you have to pay attention that all the subviews (the ones you want them to catch the event) must have the user interaction enabled otherwise your main view will capture the events for the subviews too and you will end up debugging and debugging without understanding what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4:**

```
let clickGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.onUiViewClick))
uiView.addGestureRecognizer(clickGesture)

 @objc func onUiViewClick(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    }
```